# Town vs City, why they can be used interchangeably in novel?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, questions

I know that this is a simple question, but it does made me wonder. This is what I found after reading quite a lot of novels and often happened: 
Why does City of something was sometimes called town when other people speak? Why they not just stay on saying a city, a "city" and instead often change it to "town" as they see fit.
 Does town here specified something in particular and that's why they were used instead of city like how it should be?

Comment: Growing up in the suburbs of Melbourne, going to town meant going to the Melbourne CBD. We didn't speak of going to the "city".

Comment: Even central London is (or used to be) traditionally referred to as 'town'. There was a famous BBC radio programme of the mid-20th century called "In Town Tonight".

Comment: In the UK at least, city status is a [formal designation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_status_in_the_United_Kingdom) granted by the Queen.  Cities are a subset of towns and a city can correctly be called a town, just as a car can be correctly called a vehicle.

Comment: I see... my native language doesn't have a different word for town and city. No wonder I'm confuse. So, it wouldn't be incorrect to call a city a town.

Comment: In the US, the general term is "municipality", and it can be either a city or town depending on the form of government.

Comment: But in informal contexts we're not strict about the distinction. New York is a city, but they still use idioms like "downtown" and "doing the town".

Comment: Sometimes you want one syllable, and sometimes you want more. An obliging language allows both.